# Clipper bin2i and i2bin needed in Java

Tags: java, xbase, clipper

I am converting/migrating  a good old clipper xbase program to Java. As the old program is still running, I need to be compatible, when writing data in Java to the databases. It works really well, until now.

For that I need the functions i2bin and bin2i from clipper to be running in Java.

See here for i2Bin: http://www.marinas-gui.org/projects/harbour_manual/i2bin.htm

I can read the clipper written i2bin data with: 
cData is a String containing the an int coded as char beginning after first char:

```
char [] array = cData .substring(1).toCharArray();
int nLen = (int) array [0];
```

But I can not write a correct int coded as char in Java. So I got a

```
int len = 8;
char clen = (char) len;
```

and I get a '\b' but with only one character. The clipper function bin2i
can not interpret it correctly. If I add a space to the char

```
String data = clen + " "
```

I get the right length for bin2i but it is not the length 8 anymore. Maybe it is coded via Ascii 32?

Anyway, how can I do it right?

regards,
Peter

Comment: My Java is not really good but you can try: `String data = ((char)(len % 256)) + ((char)((int)(len / 256) % 256)`

Answer (score 0):

you want this:

```
public byte[] i2bin(short i)
{
 byte[] ret = new byte[2];
 ret[0] = (byte)(i & 0xff);
 ret[1] = (byte)((i>>>8) & 0xff);
 return ret;
}
```

do not use char or string as they are locale/charset dependent